# Google Drive API adding some string in file

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I have been trying to replace files using google API only with the Python HTTPS module. But when I replace it. It adds some string to the file with text.
Code:

```
headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(Acesstoken),
    }

files = {  
    'file': open("./Test.txt", "rb"),
    "mimeType": "text/plain"
    }


r2= requests.patch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + updateFileId,
    headers= headers,
    files = files,
)
```

Text On Google Drive Before Replacing File:

```
Test
```

Text On Google Drive After Replacing File:

```
--a164a6e367e3577590ab9eb85b487e21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Test.txt"

Test 2
--a164a6e367e3577590ab9eb85b487e21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mimeType"; filename="mimeType"

text/plain
--a164a6e367e3577590ab9eb85b487e21--
```

Advance Thanks to @DaImTo

I've just unlocked talk in chat. I don't mind talking.

Comment: When I try to update the zip file. Adding strings make file corrupted

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To replace the file or to update its content? The update method you are using is for updating file's metadata and/or content.

Comment: While I replace files in Google drive.Google updating content in the file. Like it was a written `test ` in test.txt google add some string to txt file content as shown in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that in your script, the endpoint is required to be modified. In your situation, please add the query parameter of `uploadType=media` as follows.

By the way, in this script, it supposes that the file of Google Drive is the text file. From your comment, it seems that you are trying to overwrite the ZIP file as text data. In this case, the mimeType is not changed. So I would like to recommend to be the same mimeType between a file on Google Drive and the uploading file.

### Pattern 1

If you want to update the text file on Google Drive by `./Test.txt`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this script, the text file on Google Drive is overwritten by `./Test.txt`.

```py
import requests

accessToken = '###' # Please set your access token.
updateFileId = '###' # Please set the file ID fot the text file on Google Drive.

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}
file = open("./Test.txt", "rb")
r2 = requests.patch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + updateFileId + "?uploadType=media",
    headers=headers,
    data=file,
)
```

### Pattern 2

If you want to append the text file on Google Drive by `./Test.txt`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
import io
import requests

accessToken = '###' # Please set your access token.
updateFileId = '###' # Please set the file ID fot the text file on Google Drive.

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}

r1 = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + updateFileId + "?alt=media", headers=headers)

file = open("./Test.txt", "rt")
merged = r1.text + file.read()
r2 = requests.patch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/" + updateFileId + "?uploadType=media",
    headers=headers,
    data=io.BytesIO(bytes(merged, 'utf-8')),
)
```

- In this case, first, the text data is retrieved. And, by merging the texts of downloaded text and the text of `./Test.txt`, the text file is updated.

### Note:

- If you want to overwrite a ZIP file on Google Drive, please use a sample ZIP file as the uploading file.

### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: However, it continues to behave the same way.

Comment: @Ankit Jingala Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `However, it continues to behave the same way.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested my proposed script, the text file on Google Drive is correctly overwritten by new text data. I deeply apologize that my test worked fine. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. So in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to test it.

Comment: @Ankit Jingala By the way, about `same way` of `However, it continues to behave the same way.`, in this case, it is the same with your situation of "Text On Google Drive After Replacing File:"?

Comment: No need to apologize man. I am learning python and google API for 3 days. Yha the thing happen the same as `"Text On Google Drive After Replacing File:"` Where I can send you code. Or we can chat on discord? We will update the solution here?

Comment: @Ankit Jingala Thank you for replying. From `Yha the thing happen the same as "Text On Google Drive After Replacing File:" Where I can send you code.`, in this case, I'm worried that you might not be using my proposed script. Because when my sample script is run, the text file on Google Drive is correctly overwritten by the text data of the local PC. In this case, the result is not the same with `Text On Google Drive After Replacing File:`. So, can you confirm it again?

Comment: Hey @Tanike. I uploaded a simple/text file to google drive. I want to create a script for updating/replacing files. I create code for updating the file script as you can see in the question. The file I uploaded contains the string `Test` when I update/replace the file with the other file that contains `Test 2` The code adds some string to the file as you can see in `Text On Google Drive After Replacing File:`. The file I uploaded before replacing/updating is the `.txt` file I use for the update is also `.txt`.I just need to replace the file with the same `fileId`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242616/discussion-between-ankit-jingala-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Ankit Jingala Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. I think that in your situation, first, it is required to remove the issue that the result using my proposed script is the same with `Text On Google Drive After Replacing File:`. Because when I tested my proposed script, the text file on Google Drive is replaced or appended by the local text data. I deeply apologize I cannot replicate your current situation.

Comment: @Ankit Jingala But I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue using my proposed script? By this, I would like to test it.

Comment: It's working fine with the first modification